# sqlite: how to modify a columns contents in a non trivial way [example]

Tags: sql, sqlite

im learning sql (sqlite)...

question: how to elegantly convert one columns content into another column?

example:

i have a table `eventid` with a column `orgdate` that contain dates in a format that should be converted as indicated below

orgdate examples   =>  resulting newdate format

```
"September  18, 2015" => "2015-09-18" -- existence of multiple spaces in orgdate
"September 5, 2015"   => "2015-09-05" -- prepended 0 on day part of result
"september 5, 2015"   => "2015-09-05" -- existence of different letter cases in input
```

in the code example below, columns `orgdate` and `newdate` are contained in `eventtable` and the `newdate` (nulls to start with) is modified by the procedure.

```
WITH tmpview(orgdate, eventid, cleandate) AS ( -- first create a "clean" date to work on in the subsequent UPDATE
      SELECT orgdate, eventid,
           replace( -- replace Nspaces=>1space "hack" via non printable char(17) char(18) sequence
               replace(
                    replace(
                          replace(  -- replace ',' with space
                                 orgdate,
                                 ",", ' '), 
                          " ", char(17)||char(18)), 
                    char(18)||char(17),''),
               char(17)||char(18),' ')
       FROM eventtable)
UPDATE eventtable SET newdate = 
    (SELECT
         substr(cleandate,length(cleandate)-3,4) || '-' || -- get year YYYY
         CASE substr(upper(cleandate), 1, 3) -- get month MM
             WHEN 'JAN' THEN '01'
             WHEN 'FEB' THEN '02'
             WHEN 'MAR' THEN '03'
             WHEN 'APR' THEN '04'
             WHEN 'MAY' THEN '05'
             WHEN 'JUN' THEN '06'
             WHEN 'JUL' THEN '07'
             WHEN 'AUG' THEN '08'
             WHEN 'SEP' THEN '09'
             WHEN 'OCT' THEN '10'
             WHEN 'NOV' THEN '11'
             WHEN 'DEC' THEN '12'
             ELSE "*ERROR*" || substr(upper(cleandate), 1, 3) 
         END || '-' ||
         CASE length(replace(substr(cleandate, instr(cleandate," ")+1, 2)," ",""))  -- get day DD
             WHEN 1 THEN "0"           -- prepend 0 if length is 1
             WHEN 2 THEN ""
         END ||
         replace(substr(cleandate, instr(cleandate," ")+1, 2)," ","")
     FROM tmpview
     WHERE 
         tmpview.orgdate = eventtable.orgdate and tmpview.eventid = eventtable.eventid );
```

this code obviously is very long and naive, my questions:

1. how to achieve the same result much more succintly?
2. as a first modification, how to avoid repetitions in the code via aliases, eg. for the CASE expression `replace(substr(cleandate, instr(cleandate," ")+1, 2)` which is duplicated further on
3. how not to rely on the newdate column already existing, but creating it in the same procedure?

of course, i can envision getting a very much cleaner and intelligble procedure via several stages of temporary tables, but i wonder what is the idiomatic way of going about this.

thanks for any answers, i think seeing this by example, will greatly help me get a good head start on sql and maybe can serve others as an addition to the pool of examples out there (i have tried to find answers to the posed questions in other examples but have been unable to synthesise them into what i need)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no simple transformation of the format you have to `YYYY-MM-DD`.
You must use the string functions that SQLite supports:

```
UPDATE eventtable
SET newdate = 
  SUBSTR(orgdate, -4) || '-' ||
  CASE UPPER(SUBSTR(TRIM(orgdate), 1, 3))
    WHEN 'JAN' THEN '01'
    WHEN 'FEB' THEN '02'
    WHEN 'MAR' THEN '03'
    WHEN 'APR' THEN '04'
    WHEN 'MAY' THEN '05'
    WHEN 'JUN' THEN '06'
    WHEN 'JUL' THEN '07'
    WHEN 'AUG' THEN '08'
    WHEN 'SEP' THEN '09'
    WHEN 'OCT' THEN '10'
    WHEN 'NOV' THEN '11'
    WHEN 'DEC' THEN '12'
  END || '-' ||
  REPLACE(SUBSTR(SUBSTR(orgdate, 1, INSTR(orgdate, ',') - 1), -2), ' ', '0')
```

This covers the cases that you mention in your question.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=fb5a3a6ffadce0031ceb310622d1d0ed).
Results:

```
> | orgdate    |
> | :--------- |
> | 2015-09-18 |
> | 2015-09-05 |
> | 2015-09-05 |
```

Comment: very cool, many thx! even though you dont need it in your query, could you also tell me if it is possible to alias the CASE expressions "decision value", as asked in 3)?

Comment: I missed the `newdate` in my query. Do you mean that you want just a SELECT query instead of UPDATE? Because an alias is not needed in this UPDATE statement.

Comment: its more of a general programming question, how to alias the x-part in a CASE x WHEN ... THEN ..., so that x can be referred to via the alias later on instead of duplicating a possibly long expression

Comment: Check 2 examples here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=4afa120ba34306d17f62d678453627d6 The 1st uses a CTE.